# How can get the subtract percentage from the max value of consecutive rows?

Tags: mysql, max

I'm displaying the max value from the column "col1_val" grouped by the column "date_rehearsal", here is the demo:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45112d/1

```
|id|  |col1_val|  |date_rehearsal|
  2     800            2022-07-01
  3     500            2021-04-01
  6     700            2020-08-04
```

I'm trying to get the percentage sustraction from the previous row to check if the value increased or decreased.

The Final result display should be this:

```
|id|  |col1_val|  |date_rehearsal|   |diference_betwen_consecutive_rows|
  2     800            2022-07-01        (800-500)/100 =  3 %
  3     500            2021-04-01        (500-700)/100 = -2 %  
  6     700            2020-08-04                         0 %
```

Can you please help me with this problem?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead if you use recent version

Comment: I checked and it Is different with the example posted

Comment: What do you mean?  What did you check? What is different?

Comment: I used the example but its not displaying records http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad1792/11

Comment: ah. sqlfiddle.com seems to just support mysql 5.6, which is not even a supported version anymore.  window functions require mysql 8 or mariadb 10.2+.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=77b6e61d0d0318c295511b37c84108c0